# Reindex Pandas Series case insensitive (Combining matches)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas series with string indices and integer values:  (My actual series has >1000 entries)

|  | Count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| bear | 2 |
| cat | 3 |
| Apple | 10 |
| pig | 20 |
| Cat | 30 |
| ApPlE | 100 |

I would like to re-index to all title case.

|  | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Bear | 2 |
| Apple | 111 |
| Pig | 20 |
| Cat | 33 |

The order doesn't matter.

I worked out how to do this with a dictionary and a loop.

```
miXedCaseSeRies = pd.Series({"apple": 1, "bear": 2  ,"cat": 3,"Apple" : 10, "pig": 20, "Cat":30 , "ApPle":100 })
tcDict ={}
for ind,val in miXedCaseSeRies.iteritems():
    ind = ind.lower()
    if ind in tcDict.keys():
        tcDict[ind] = tcDict[ind]+val 
    else:
        tcDict[ind] = val

Titlecaseseries = pd.Series(tcDict)
```

...But answers like this one: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758) (Spoiler: ***"DON'T"***) make me feel guilty for not finding a better way.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the index to first character uppercase only with `string.captialized()` then groupby index and aggregate sum function

```py
df = df.rename(index=lambda x: x.capitalize())
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg({'Count': 'sum'})
# or
df = df.groupby(df.index)['Count'].agg('sum').to_frame()
```

```
print(df)

       Count
Apple    111
Bear       2
Cat       33
Pig       20
```

Assume you use your Series

```py
miXedCaseSeRies = pd.Series({"apple": 1, "bear": 2  ,"cat": 3,"Apple" : 10, "pig": 20, "Cat":30 , "ApPle":100 })

miXedCaseSeRies = miXedCaseSeRies.rename(index=lambda x: x.capitalize())
df = miXedCaseSeRies.to_frame('Count').groupby(miXedCaseSeRies.index).agg({'Count': 'sum'})
```